# Android: bluetooth change events occur before AudioManager changes

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to detect when a bluetooth earbud or headset is turned on or turned off.  The AudioManager class has these methods: `isBluetoothA2dpOn()` and `isBluetoothScoOn()` which seem to work fine with my test devices.  These methods accurately return the state of the bluetooth devices.

Next I set up a BroadcastReceiver to get notified for changes in bluetooth connectivity status.  Here is the code to setup the BroadcastReceiver:

```
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);      // catches bluetooth ON/OFF (the major case)
    intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED);       // catches when the actual bt device connects.
    intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);
    intentFilter.addAction(AudioManager.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED);    // does NOT catch devices connected/disconnected
    registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
```

And here is the BroadcastReceiver:

```
        mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent itt) {
            String action = itt.getAction();
            switch (action) {
                // This just gets notified if bluetooth is turned OFF or ON.
                case BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED: {
                    int extraState = itt.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, MY_ERROR_STATE);
                    int extraPreviousState = itt.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_PREVIOUS_STATE, MY_ERROR_STATE);
                    String str = "   bluetooth state changed from " + extraPreviousState + " to " + extraState;
                    Log.d(TAG, str);
                    break;
                }

                case AudioManager.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED: {
                    int newState = itt.getIntExtra(AudioManager.EXTRA_SCO_AUDIO_STATE, MY_ERROR_STATE);
                    int prevState = itt.getIntExtra(AudioManager.EXTRA_SCO_AUDIO_PREVIOUS_STATE, MY_ERROR_STATE);
                    String str = "   bluetooth device updated from " + prevState + " to " + newState;
                    Log.d(TAG, str);
                    break;
                }

                case BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED: {
                    BluetoothDevice device = itt.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                    String str = "   connected to bluetooth device: " + device.getName() + ", " + device.describeContents();
                    Log.d(TAG, str);
                    break;
                }

                case BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED: {
                    BluetoothDevice device = itt.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                    String str = "   disconnected from bluetooth device: " + device.getName() + ", " + device.describeContents();
                    Log.d(TAG, str);
                    break;
                }
            }
        Log.d(TAG, "bluetooth sco = " + mAudioMgr.isBluetoothScoOn());
        Log.d(TAG, "bluetooth a2dp = " + mAudioMgr.isBluetoothA2dpOn());
        }
    };
```

Now the BroadcastReceiver is notified whenever there is a change in the various bluetooth and device states.  For example, turning on my bluetooth earbuds causes the ACL_CONNECTED to fire (as expected), with the extra data indicating that it is now in an ON state.

But when the code hits the log statements, bluetooth a2dp will still register as turned OFF.  Weird, as the code just received a noticed that it was turned on.

If I wait a few seconds, the `mAudioMgr.isBluetoothxxx()` will return the correct result.

Anyone have an explanation of this seemingly contradictory behavior?

Comment: I have the same problem, have you solved it?

Comment: Nope.  I wish I had a solution, sigh.